# Cause of inferred latches (not else or default statement) in Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, quartus

Quartus is telling me that I have inferred latches for input_val, ii, output_val, delayed, and addr_to_rom. I have looked at previous posts and made changes so that all my if statements have an else component and that my case statement has a default option.

What else could be causing all of these inferred latches?
(updated code below)

```
   module   simple_fir(clk, reset_n, output_val); 
    
    parameter               data_width = 8; 
    parameter               size = 1024;    

    
    input   wire                clk;
    input   wire                reset_n;
    //input     reg [(data_width):0]    input_val;
    reg [(data_width):0]    input_val;
    output  reg [data_width:0]      output_val;

    reg     [(data_width):0]    delayed;
    reg     [data_width:0]      to_avg;     
    reg         [9:0]           ii ;
    reg         [9:0]           i ;
    reg     [data_width:0]      val;
    reg     [data_width:0]      output_arr [(size-1):0];

    
    logic [(data_width):0] data_from_rom; //precalculated 1 Hz sine wave
    logic [9:0] addr_to_rom;

    initial delayed = 0;
    initial i = 0;
    initial ii = 0;
    
    
    //port map to ROM
    rom_data input_data(
    .clk(clk),
    .addr(addr_to_rom), //text file?
    .data(data_from_rom)
    );
        
    //Moore FSM
    localparam [3:0]
    s0=0, s1 = 1, s2 = 2, s3 = 3, s4 = 4, s5 = 5, s6 = 6;
    
    reg [3:0] state_reg, state_next;
    initial state_next = 0;
    always @(posedge clk, negedge reset_n) begin //posedge clk, reset_n
        if (reset_n == 'b0) begin //reset is active low
        state_reg <= s0;
        end else begin
        state_reg <= state_next;
        end
    end
            
    always @* begin 
        state_next = state_reg; // default state_next
        case (state_reg)
            s0 : begin //initial state, reset state
                    if (!reset_n) begin
            output_val = 0;
            delayed = 0; 
            to_avg= 0; 
            i = 0;
            ii = 0;
            end else begin
            state_next = s1;
            end
            end
            s1 : begin
                if (ii>(size-2)) begin
                ii = 0;
                end else begin
                addr_to_rom = ii;
                end
                input_val = input_val;
                delayed = delayed; 
                state_next = s2;
            end
            s2 : begin
                input_val = data_from_rom;
                ii = ii+1;
                delayed = delayed; 
                state_next = s3;
            end
            s3 : begin
                delayed = input_val;
                state_next = s4;
            end
            s4 : begin
                addr_to_rom = ii;
                input_val = input_val;
                delayed = delayed; 
                state_next = s5;
            end
            s5 : begin
                input_val = data_from_rom;
                delayed = delayed;
                //i=i+1;
                //ii <= ii+1;
                state_next = s6;
            end
           s6 : begin
                to_avg = input_val + delayed; //summing two values
                val = (to_avg >> 1);    //taking the average
                output_arr[ii-1] = val; //indexing starts on [2]
                output_val = val; 
                state_next = s0;
                input_val = input_val;
            end
            default: begin
                addr_to_rom = addr_to_rom;
                data_from_rom = data_from_rom;
                delayed = delayed;
                input_val = input_val;
                to_avg = to_avg;
                val = val;
                output_val = output_val;
                ii = ii;
                end
        endcase
    end 

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to look at the ways state machines are programmed. Usually states are calculated using flop and the final assignment is a combinatorial. You have it vice versa.  Therefore you have issues. Something like the following should work for you. Sorry, i did not test it. The code needs to use non-blocking assignments except in the place where you caculate an  intermediate value.

```
    always @* 
        state_reg = state_next;

    always @(posedge clk, negedge reset_n) begin //posedge clk, reset_n
        if (reset_n == 'b0) begin //reset is active low
            state_next <= s0;
        end 
        else begin
          case (state_reg)
            S0: begin
              output_val <= 0;
              delayed <= 0; 
              i <= 0;
              ii <= 0;
            end
            s1 : begin
                if (ii>(size-2)) begin
                   ii <= 0;
                end else begin
                   addr_to_rom <= ii;
                end
                input_val <= input_val;
                delayed <= delayed; 
                state_next <= s2;
            end
            s2 : begin
                input_val <= data_from_rom;
                ii <= ii+1;
                state_next <= s3;
            end
            s3 : begin
                delayed <= input_val;
                state_next <= s4;
            end
            s4 : begin
                addr_to_rom <= ii;
                state_next <= s5;
            end
            s5 : begin
                input_val <= data_from_rom;
                state_next <= s6;
            end
            s6 : begin
                // calculating intermediate value, need blocking assignments here
                to_avg = input_val + delayed; //need blocking here
                val = (to_avg >> 1);    //need blocking here

                output_arr[ii-1] <= val; //indexing starts on [2]
                output_val <= val; 
                state_next <= s0; 
            end
        endcase
      end // else
    end // always
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 6 states in your combo `always` block, but you are assigning to `delayed` in only 3 of them.  This implies that you want to retain state, which infers latches.  You should make sure `delayed` is assigned some value in all states (and in all branches of `if/else`, if applicable.

Also, you have an incomplete sensitivity list.  You likely want to change:

```
always @(state_reg) begin
```

to:

```
always @* begin
```

`@*` is the implicit sensitivity list, which triggers the `always` block whenever a change occurs to any signal on the RHS of an assignment.

Comment: I have made all the changed you suggested and I'm still getting all of the inferred latch errors. Was there anything else that could be causing this? (I've updated thee above code)

Comment: @Tarashi99: You should not overwrite your original code because that renders this answer as useless.  The updated code now has a different problem: combinational loops: `delayed = delayed`.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you used a coding style that a default assignment `state_next = state_reg` is placed at the very top of the `always` block. That makes `state_next` always have a legal driver if it is not explicitly assigned. This is also required for other combinational signals. Otherwise, latch inferred. Besides, the signal `data_from_rom`, which I assume is an output from module `rom_data`, has mutiple drivers.